# Unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)

Tags: java, android, fileoutputstream

Can someone throw some light on these errors

```
03-23 14:24:53.641 31726-32030/com.vpn W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)
03-23 14:24:53.644 31726-32030/com.vpn W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)
03-23 14:24:53.647 31726-32030/com.vpn I/dalvikvm: Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.sink
03-23 14:24:53.647 31726-32030/com.vpn W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 22324: Ljava/nio/file/Files;.newOutputStream (Ljava/nio/file/Path;[Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)Ljava/io/OutputStream;
03-23 14:24:53.647 31726-32030/com.vpn D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
```

Comment: Please if our help was valuable, mark the question as solved ;)

Answer (score 6):

From [Square/okhttp FAQ's](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/FAQs)

> OkHttp supports some APIs that require Java 7+ or Android API 20+. If
>   you run OkHttp on earlier Android releases, dalvikvm's verifier will
>   warn about the missing methods. This isn't a problem and **you can
>   ignore the warnings.**

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 3):

```
W/dalvikvm
I/dalvikvm
D/dalvikvm
```

These are **W**arning, **I**nfo, and **D**ebug, respectively.

```
E/dalvikvm
```

This would be an **E**rror, but you don't have any of those.

As far as the messages are concerned, @g2o has you covered on that, but this message `unable to resolve static method 22324: Ljava/nio/file/Files;.newOutputStream (Ljava/nio/file/Path;[Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)Ljava/io/OutputStream` means a method `newOutputStream` could not be found that uses `java.nio.file.Path[]` and `java.nio.file.OpenOption[]`.